# Given a starting and ending coordinate in an array, mark array slots to draw a rectangle

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 10x10 array and I know where the starting and ending points of a rectangle are. The rectangle can be 1x3, 2x2, 3x2, etc.

Given the starting and ending coordinates, I need to mark where the rectangle is in the 10x10 array.

**Example one (correct):**

Upper Left Node: [0, 1]

Lower Right Node: [1, 2]

```
|--0--| |--x--| |--x--| |--0--|
|--0--| |--x--| |--x--| |--0--|
|--0--| |--0--| |--0--| |--0--|
|--0--| |--0--| |--0--| |--0--|
```

**Example two (incorrect):**

Upper Left Node: [1,3]

Lower Right Node: [3,3]

Current output:

```
|--0--| |--0--| |--0--| |--0--|
|--0--| |--0--| |--0--| |--x--|
|--0--| |--0--| |--0--| |--0--|
|--0--| |--0--| |--0--| |--0--|
```

Desired Output:

```
|--0--| |--0--| |--0--| |--0--|
|--0--| |--0--| |--0--| |--x--|
|--0--| |--0--| |--0--| |--x--|
|--0--| |--0--| |--0--| |--x--|
```

This is what I tried:

```
$width = $lowerRightNode[1] - $upperLeftNode[1] + 1;
echo 'width: ' . $width .'<br/>';
for($i=$upperLeftNode[0]; $i < $upperLeftNode[0] + $width; $i++) {
    for($z=$upperLeftNode[1]; $z <= $lowerRightNode[1]; $z++) {
        $this->_grid[$i][$z] = 'x';
        echo $i . ' ' . $z .'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is really like a flood-fill problem. You have a fixed 2D grid as an array, and you want to fill a specific area based on X/Y coordinates. I've simplified the implementation below to demonstrate how this can be done.

```
const GRID_WIDTH  = 10;
const GRID_HEIGHT = 10;

// Coordinates are described as [[y1, x1], [y2, x2]]
$coordinates = [[1,3], [3,3]];

// Create the grid
$grid = array_fill(0, GRID_WIDTH, array_fill(0, GRID_HEIGHT, '-'));

// Plot the coordinates on the grid
for ($y = 0; $y < GRID_WIDTH; $y++) { // plot Y
    for ($x = 0; $x < GRID_HEIGHT; $x++) { // plot X
        if ($y >= $coordinates[0][0] && $y <= $coordinates[0][1]) {
            if ($x >= $coordinates[1][0] && $x <= $coordinates[1][1]) {
                $grid[$y][$x] = 'X';
            }
        }
    }
}

// Print the grid
foreach ($grid as $x => $y) {
    foreach ($y as $plot) {
        echo " $plot ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output should be something like this:

```
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  X  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  X  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  X  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
```

And in your first example `[0,1]`, `[1,2]` it would look like this:

```
 -  X  X  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  X  X  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
```

The key here is to make sure that as we scan the grid (from X to Y) that the coordinates of X1, Y1, X2, and Y2 are within the bounds of the cursor. This allows us to plot one cell at a time as long as we are inside of these bounds (inclusive). This is done by the check `if ($y >= $coordinates[0][0] && $y <= $coordinates[0][1])` and `if ($x >= $coordinates[1][0] && $x <= $coordinates[1][1])`. Since calculating the width of the coordinates is not enough (*which is what your implementation above is doing*). Because it doesn't identify a height boundary.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the rectangles you want to draw, using the code you already have (although with no need to compute `$width`):

```
$rects = array(array(array(1, 3), array(3, 3)),
              array(array(0, 1), array(1, 2))
              );
$grid = array_fill(0, 10, array_fill(0, 10, '0'));
foreach ($rects as $r) {
    list($upperLeftNode, $lowerRightNode) = $r;
    for($x = $upperLeftNode[0]; $x <= $lowerRightNode[0]; $x++) {
        for($y = $upperLeftNode[1]; $y <= $lowerRightNode[1]; $y++) {
            $grid[$x][$y] = 'x';
        }
    }
}
foreach ($grid as $row) {
    echo implode(' ', $row) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0 x x 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 x x x 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 x 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 x 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ogdPI)